# Extract table column values using xpath excluding <sup>

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrap some table column values using scrapy and stuck on how to get a column value. The code right now is

```
response.xpath('//table//tr//td[4]//text()').extract()
```

It does extract the column values but the problem is some columns does have

```
<td> value 1 <sup> sup text </sup> </td>
```

and the return values are `value1 , sup text` which is not what i do require .I need only  i tried the code with `td[4][not(sup)]`  but it does completely ignore the columns with `<sup>` .

Is there a way to get the values excluding `<sup>` .

Comment: You've said what you DON'T want, but you haven't said what you DO want. For example, if the input is `<td>H<sub>2</sub>O</td>, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: What i need was `H` , the answer below gives it

Comment: No, the answer you accepted returns two text nodes, containing "H" and "O" respectively. In some contexts (but we don't know the context) when you select two nodes, the second will be ignored. But in general if you only want the first text node then you should add a predicate `[1]`.

Comment: Sorry , it does works in my context ,........ the answer is not  returning `<sup>` value , it works perfectly for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
//td[4]/text()
```

to get *child text node*. Note that `//td[4]//text()` - returns *descendant text nodes* (including text from `sup`)